# USB speaker not detected

Tags: usb, sound, pulseaudio, alsa, udev

I am connecting an USB speaker but it the speaker gets detected on USB buts gets rejected after a while. However it works in Fedora

```
[ 9548.214066] usb 5-3: new full-speed USB device number 19 using ohci-pci
[ 9548.375162] usb 5-3: config 1 has an invalid interface number: 3 but max is 2
[ 9548.375175] usb 5-3: config 1 has no interface number 2
[ 9548.381140] usb 5-3: New USB device found, idVendor=10d6, idProduct=1100
[ 9548.381151] usb 5-3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[ 9548.381158] usb 5-3: Product: USB Audio
[ 9548.381163] usb 5-3: Manufacturer: ACTIONS
[ 9550.015478] usb 5-3: 1:1: cannot get freq at ep 0x2
[ 9550.037516] usb 5-3: 3:0: cannot get min/max values for control 2 (id 3)
[ 9550.047504] usbhid 5-3:1.3: can't add hid device: -62
[ 9550.047537] usbhid: probe of 5-3:1.3 failed with error -62
[ 9550.047846] usb 5-3: USB disconnect, device number 19
[ 9550.057181] systemd-udevd[7156]: Failed to apply ACL on /dev/snd/controlC2: No such file or directory
[ 9550.057192] systemd-udevd[7156]: Failed to apply ACL on /dev/snd/controlC2: No such file or directory
[ 9550.058785] systemd-udevd[7160]: Failed to apply ACL on /dev/snd/pcmC2D0p: No such file or directory
[ 9550.058792] systemd-udevd[7160]: Failed to apply ACL on /dev/snd/pcmC2D0p: No such file or directory
```